# how do you restrict directory path to role?

Tags: users, uri, files

How would you go about restricting a specific directory path to a role?

www.example.com/example1/example3/example4

How do you restrict role access to the directory example1 so that example3 and 4 are restricted automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search did the job:

https://www.drupal.org/project/path_access

The module will enable you to restrict access to certain paths per role. Each role has a page of either ACCESS ONLY or CANNOT ACCESS paths. Easy to set bunch permissions if you play with many roles at once.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what that path is? Drupal has many kinds of paths and default permissions out of the box. If this was a Book hierarchy default permissions exist for books. The same for Taxonomy terms and other types of content. If this was a Views based path, you could configure Access rules in your view.

Without any 3rd party module support I would look at [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) if you are defining these paths yourself or [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) if they are provided by another module.

Drupal Roles are not a reliable way to deem access to content -- I would alter the `access callback` for this path to use `user_access` permission values and create a custom permission such as `view my custom site area` and give that permission to  desired roles. Then I would an `access arguments` of `view my custom site area` so the `user_access` check works on those paths.

The [Workbench Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access) module can do what you're asking if you define the Access rules using the `Menu Scheme` and not Taxonomies, but this module only works for `Nodes` last I checked.

> Workbench Access provide the hierarchical permissions across
>   "Sections" of your web site. You can use menus, taxonomy, or create
>   your own hierarchical structure for controlling access to a piece of
>   content.

Comment: Thanks! But I found an easier solution that works for me :-) Linking below

Comment: good job, if you read the module description you'll see they use the exact same formula I described :)